# Integer class in Java

Tags: java, class, integer

I can't figure out why the output is different.
The output is same only in the range -128 to 127.

```
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Integer i1=122;
        Integer i2=122;

        if(i1==i2)
            System.out.println("Both are same");
        if(i1.equals(i2))
            System.out.println("Both are meaningful same");
    }
}
```

Output:
    Both are same
    Both are meaningful same

```
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i1=1000;
        Integer i2=1000;

        if(i1==i2)
            System.out.println("Both are same");
        if(i1.equals(i2))
            System.out.println("Both are meaningful same");
    }
}
```

Output:
    Both are meaningful same

Comment: always use the equals.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question... a simple search would have answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've encountered a caveat in the Java language where autoboxing for "small" values has a slightly different rule than autoboxing. ("Small" in this case means a number in the range of 127 to -128, as in a signed `byte` in C.) From [JLS 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.7):

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127, then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. **It is always the case that r1 == r2.**

(Emphasis is mine.)

In the second example (where `i1=i2=1000`), the `if(i1==i2)` comparison results in `false` because the value of both objects is greater than 127. In that case `==` is a *referential comparison*, i.e. checking to see if the objects are actually the same object.